# Disable ping on Windows (not block)

Tags: windows, ping, icmp

How can I disable Windows ping from replying?
Is there a service I can kill?
I don't want to block it via a firewall, as I can my own ping service running (custom application).

tia.

Comment: @ClassStacker, ICMP has no ports as it works inside IP, but essentially yes, I have the same. The reason is elaborate, but simply put, I have an app that re-invents the ping for custom usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping is part of the basic functionality of TCP protocol. If you want to restrict the reply without using firewall you would have to change the protocol.

You would have to implement your own flavour of the TCP protocol and not use the windows version.

If you are knowledgeable in development, you could look for an Open Source TCP protocol like [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/embeddedtcp.html) change the source code to meet your needs.

Comment: I figured as much. My best solution is to actively run both, and handle both requests and have my app "tell the difference" between the default TCP stack and mine.

Comment: Since I don't want to stop any other calls but echo reply (destination unreachable I don't want to interfere with).